# Find nested documents by id

Tags: elasticsearch

Elasticsearch has [ids](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-ids-query.html) query to find documents by id. 
I tried to use it in nested query:

```
{
    "query": {
        "nested": {
           "path": "nestedField",
           "query": {"ids":{ "values": ["nestedDocumentId" ] }},
           "inner_hits" : {}    
        } 
    }
}
```

But this query looks at parent document id, not at nested.
Can I use [ids](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-ids-query.html) query for finding nested documents by their ids?

Comment: Why do you need that? The id of the nested documents is automatically created and you cannot control that.

Comment: @AndreiStefan I'm creating a *"hasMany"* relationship using _nested objects_. I decided to not use _parent-child_ because _nested objects_ approach is faster. I need to find object of any Document (nested or not) by one or several ids.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The id of the nested documents is automatically created and you cannot control that.

The solution is to index that `id` in the nested document itslef as regular field and do a `terms` filter instead of `ids`.